# Silent, power saving mini-server for home

Tags: memory, webserver, sql-server, single-board

I am looking for hardware to make a small, silent, power saving mini-server for use at home. My specifications are:

- Small
- Fanless / Small fan
- Able to run Windows server OS
- Has 2GB of RAM, ideally 4GB

I'm following the single board computers available out there, but most of them have a memory limit (1-2GB). 2GB will do it for now, but might not be future proof. I want to be able to run a database server on it and a a couple of personal sites.

Any ideas on hardware that can do the job? Suggestions on forthcoming hardware are welcomed.

Comment: Questions asking for hardware recommendations are [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @Izam: Sorry for that. Please feel free to move the topic to a relevant stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the "crazy Mac guy" but a Mac Mini serves this purpose perfectly.  It's tiny, practically inaudible even at full load, runs Windows natively, can be upgraded to 16GB of RAM if need be, and has enough room for two 2.5" hard drives.

Comment: +1. It is definetely a good alternative. Thank you!